# Database XML field with constraints

Tags: sql, xml, database

I'm doing an application, where I have customers that can require data extension in the database schema.

To do data extension I have a XML data field, where I store each customers extension.

```
CustomerID |    Name   | XML field 
   1            Jack     <Age>24</Age>
   2            Marie    <Country>Norway</Country>
```

My question is, if Jack now wants his attribute Age to have a constraint NOT NULL, is this possible without affecting the other customers?

My other question is, if Marie wants an index on attribute Country, is this possible without affecting the other customers?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a Constraint NOT NULL as an XSD for the XML-File which would require another nullable Column.

```
CustomerID ¦ Name  ¦ XML field                 ¦ XSD field
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1     ¦ Jack  ¦ <Age>24</Age>             ¦ <xs:element name="Age" nillable="false"/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     2     ¦ Marie ¦ <Country>Norway</Country> ¦
```

Concerning the index I personally would have said that XML shouldn't be indexed. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209456/is-it-possible-to-set-an-index-inside-a-xml-column-on-sql-server-2005-sql-serv) might help you.

If you want your Constraint inside SQL then i can't help you. I believe that as Nikolas Charalambidis said you can't make conditions for cells as SQL is not build for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The `NOT NULL` constraint enforces a **column** to not accept null values. It is applied for a whole column, so you cannot.

If you want to always force any value to the selected row, you have to use triggers. Check if there's a null in the selected item and if so, you change it to a default value.